# Storyboard, drag link to an IBAction from a container view to the parent

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

Here's a trivial VC called Club

[image]

Club has a function:

```
@implementation Club
-(IBAction)clickMe
    {
    NSLog(@"Whoa!");
    }
@end
```

Now regarding **ButtonA**. Obviously in Storyboard **you can drag** from ButtonA to the function "clickMe" in "Club".

Now.  Regarding ButtonB.

Is there any way, in Storyboard, **to drag from ButtonB**, to "clickMe" in "Club"?

Perhaps using the mysterious "object" objects, or ... ??

Note that, obviously, you can make a class for the small view, and have a function:

```
@implementation SmallViewOnRight
-(IBAction)sameAsClickMe
    {
    [(Club*)self.parentViewController clickMe];
    }
@end
```

Then, you can drag from ButtonB to sameAsClickMe. But that's a complete nuisance.

Note that it's very normal to use container views like this, to handle different "areas" of your main view (particularly if you have stuff sliding around and so on, and when you have many things "on top of each other"). It's hugely convenient to move "sections" outside the main view, using container views. But it's a complete nuisance "passing up" the clicks.

Is there an obscure way to do this in Storyboard?  Cheers!

Just FTR, iOS7+ only, nothing older

Note - going in the "other direction" is well-explored and easy enough to do.

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you set your `View Controller` as `Club` too. By code you could use your `Club` reference and set the action to be called from `buttonB` as one `Club`'s actions (if you need some var/let in there to update UI or elaborate)

Comment: From my experience the point of a container view is to have a separate view controller that takes care of itself so that you don't end up with one gigantic, bloated UIViewController class. The way I would handle this situation would be to make a protocol for the 2nd ViewController and set its delegate to be the ClubViewController class. Then you can do what you said and have the `sameAsClickMe` method and have it call the ClubViewController's `clickMe` method via the delegate.

Comment: Hey guys!  It's bizarre you can't just drag it in storyboard, because **they are both instantiated** so there's no reason one can't.  I'm wondering about the mysterious "object" object? Could that be relevant?  SFeuer, in my long para ("Note...") I explain the use case. You know, it's almost impossible to do really complex (particularly slide) screens without using container views as little "sub" areas. A mystery!

Comment: By the way guys I think it's a bit **conceptually weird** to make a container view use a delegate!!!  It would be as if with (say) simply a button, the view didn't just own it, the view had to go through the mechanism of becoming a delegate of the button, just to use it! A container view is "utterly part of" a view - it's not unlike "a really complex control", really.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that but you can use delegates for this behavior.

**In SecondViewController.h:**

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)clickMe;
@end

@interface SecondViewController.h: UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**In SecondViewController.m:**

```
@implementation SecondViewController 

- (IBAction) buttonBClicked:(id)sender {
 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(clickMe)] {
       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(clickMe)];
    }
}

@end
```

**In ClubViewController.m:**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ClubViewController () <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ClubViewController.m

// make yourself a delegate of SecondViewController somewhere in your code. For example, in prepareForSegue. 

-(void)clickMe {
   NSLog (@"Clicked");
}

@end
```

EDIT:
Try with Unwind Segues!
I've posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018417/1641848) on how to use them. But skip step 4.

Comment: A nice example of delegate use! Note that as I said, you'd trivially [self.parentViewController clickMe]; in code, in this situation.

Comment: I've missed that :)! But it's working? I've never tried sending a message to a parentViewController except for dismissing.

Comment: Sure :). Or I could perform a selector after checking if it responds to the call.

Comment: Cool article! I was thinking about Unwind Segues because you can hook a UIButton's action to an Unwind Segue Action Method

Comment: I wouldn't personally recommend making a **container** view a protocol/delegate .. like I say above, it already has a very explicit parent-child relationship.  Anyway I know how to use delegates :)  the question was is there a way to make that link, dragging in storyboard!  I wonder!!!!!!!!!